# CodeIgniter Send Email with image

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, attachment

I'm Beginner for the CI.

Here is my code in welcome.php

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


public function index()
{
$this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
public function emailSend()
{
$this->load->library('upload');
$this->load->library('email');

$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$this->upload->initialize($config);







$this->email->from($this->input->post('from'), $this->input->post('name'));
$this->email->to('taryar.t1@gmail.com');
//$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
//$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');

$this->email->subject($this->input->post('subject'));
$this->email->message($this->input->post('body'));

if($this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $attachdata=$this->upload->data();
$this->email->attach($attachdata['full_path']);
}

if($this->email->send())
    {
        echo 'Your email was sent, successfully.';
    }

    else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }

}
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

This code is only work for text and not for the attachment(image).
The error is "Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method."

how can i fixed that error??
Help me Thz you.

Comment: Have you tried using SMTP instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
        $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';

        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $to = $this->input->post('to'); // email@gmail.com
        $cc = 'email@gmail.com'; // email@gmail.com
        $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
        $message = $this->input->post('message');

        $this->email->to($to);
        $this->email->cc($cc);
        $this->email->from('info@awandevelopers.com','Awan Developers');
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);


        $config['upload_path'] = './attachments/'; // or you can use any folder like uploads
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768'; 
        $config['encrypt_name']     = true;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('files')) // files will be input attachment field name
        {
            $this->upload->display_errors();
        }else{
            $image_data = $this->upload->data();
            $fname=$image_data['file_name'];
            $fpath=$image_data['file_path'].$fname;
            $this->email->attach($fpath);

            if ($this->email->send()){
                echo "Mail Sent!";
            }
            else{
                echo "There is error in sending mail!";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the official docs..

```
$this->email->attach('/path/to/photo1.jpg');
$this->email->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|txt|php|pdf';
$config['max_size']         = '9000';
$config['encrypt_name']     = true;

$image_data = $this->upload->data();
$fname=$image_data['file_name'];
$fpath=$image_data['file_path'].$fname;

$this->email->attach($fpath);
```

The above code will solve your problem.The same problem was to me also. This is because the name of file you saved in folder is different as you attached the above code will solve it because it take the correct path of your uploads folder. Please note that the uploads folder should be in root.

Comment: what if image is from database?